# What are the dangers of missing a dose and overdose?

Tags: medications, dosage, overdose, reference-request, missed-dose

I'm a computer engineering student that would like to address this issue on my next project using prototype and maybe a web-based software or app.

But before that, I had to understand why patients need to take their doses as prescribed (on time, proper medication, and proper quantity). I hope you could help me understand this from your medical point of view.

If you could also cite some papers or sources that could either support your answer or further my understanding, I would be very grateful.

Also as medical personnel, how do you make sure that patients take their medication properly/as prescribed?

Comment: Far too broad, and makes the mistaken assumption that you can ask for professional opinions here. Please read the [help].